# Scraping JavaScript tables with VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

After reading many many threads on here, I have decided I should join the community and hopefully gain some additional knowledge by getting some answers to questions I haven't seen answered.

Currently, I am working on a VBA scraping macro that will cycle through different search request on a JavaScript rendered table. I can work the combo boxes and radio buttons to submit my request (thanks to this forum!), but I can not figure out how to pull the retrieved data out of the tables and place the data into an excel file. I am also trying to figure out how I can make an "if" statement if no results were found. Here is the code from the website when results are found. The picture also shows URL I am scraping. [Website code and URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McKxF.png)

My big issue is that I do not see ID elements anywhere to reference?

When results show up, I need to follow the hyperlink of an individual and then scrape the data that is shown.

My current code is:

```
Sub web_scraper()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_url = "https://www.sircon.com/ComplianceExpress/Inquiry/consumerInquiry.do?nonSscrb=Y"

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate my_url
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 530
    .Height = 800
    .Width = 800

Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End With

With ie.document
    .all.Item("state").selectedindex = 2
    .all.Item("state").FireEvent ("onchange")
    Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
    .all.Item("entityType")(1).Click
    Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
    .all.Item("AddressType")(1).Click
    .all.Item("maxRecords").selectedindex = 4
    .all.Item("qualificationType").selectedindex = 16
End With
```

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

For i = 1 To 607

```
        ie.document.all.Item("city").Value = Worksheets("Cycle").Cells(i, 2).Value

        For j = 1 To 676

        ie.document.all.Item("lastName").Value = Worksheets("Cycle").Cells(j, 1)
        ie.document.all.Item("submitButton").Click
```

'click first link, scrape all data from page, return, go to next result, 
'follow hyperlink and scrape page, repeat until all results have been scraped.

```
        Next j

Next i
```

The page can only pull 200 names at a time, so I am searching by city, and then by two letter combinations for last names (that are sourced from excel sheet). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding your part about the `if` statement.  Are you trying to exit an `if` statement, or are you worried that if nothing happens, there will be a syntax failure?  For the former, you can use `Exit sub`, and for the latter, it will work just fine, though without an exit statement, the system will carry on to the next line of code outside of the `if`.

Comment: At this point I think I am going to ditch VBA and go at this task with Python. VBA has to do it via browser manipulation and It will be scraping about 20k entries.