# Web scraping with excel VBA returns no values for certain sites

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from Oslo Børs related to 3months NIBOR using excel VBA. However my code do not return any values back to excel. The same code is able to retrieve table data from other similar websites, but could it be related to the ui-view set-up of the html language? I'm not very skilled on html language, so I do come to short here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
Sub NIBOR3M_oslobors()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim InternetExplorer As Object
Dim strURL As String
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim tbl As Object
        Dim rw As Object
        Dim cl As Object
        Dim nextrow As Long
        Dim I As Long

strURL = "https://www.oslobors.no/markedsaktivitet/#/details/NIBOR3M.NIBOR/overview"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .navigate strURL
    Do Until .READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
            Set doc = ie.Document

        Set ws = Worksheets("Interest rates")

        For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
            Set rng = ws.Range("M8:M8" & nextrow)
            For Each rw In tbl.Rows
                For Each cl In rw.Cells
                    rng.Value = rw.innerText
                    Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                    I = I + 1
                Next cl
                nextrow = nextrow + 1
                Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I)
                I = 0
            Next rw
        Next tbl

            .Quit
        End With

 ActiveSheet.Range("M8").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that https://www.oslobors.no uses JavaScript to load the data, the data does not exist when you request it.

Comment: @FredrikStigsson sure it's not Ajax? JavaScript would mean the values are on the users computer. I have not looked at the source since I'm typing on my phone

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Fredrik. I thought that might be a problem for the code, and I'm guessing I might find some hlp in the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904054/scraping-javascript-tables-with-vba

Comment: Perhaps you can use an API instead? That means you get all values as a json string and you parse it to the worksheet. https://oms.no/no/products/

Comment: Hi, Andreas. The purpose of the task I'm using this data for does unfortunately not justify to become a subscriber of Oslo Børs services - but it would definitely solve the problem.

Comment: @HaakonSilberg There are several XHR requests being sent that you can use. Which data do you want to retrieve? Just the tables? The chart data?

Comment: @StavrosJon I was just interested in the tables, i.e. the latest data, not historical development from the charts. Thanks for the proposed solution btw.

Comment: @HaakonSilberg Then take a look at the answer below. It's fairly easy if you familiarize yourself with the mechanics. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tables you are trying to scrape are generated by scripts, so you will not find them in the HTML document. To get your hands on the data you will need to send an XHR request.

To find out how this request should look like, you have to inspect the network traffic when the page is loaded. You can do that through your browser's developer tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> if you're using Firefox).

There you will see several requests of different types being sent. In your case, you should look for `XHR` requests of type `json`. There's a few of them. If you go through the responses of these requests, you will eventually find the one you need, as it will contain the data you want.

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

If you go through the `Headers` and the `Params` of the request you will see how the url, the body and the headers should look like. In this particular case, all the parameters are encoded into the url and the headers are not essential to the success of the request, so all you need is the url.

The response's payload is in `json` format. You can inspect its structure using a tool like [this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). Here's how it looks like:

[image]

To parse a response like that you need a parser (look at the end of this post).

**TL;DR** :

Here's how to get the data from the "Nibor 3 month" table:

```
Option Explicit

Sub oslobors()
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim respJSON As Object
Dim key As Variant
Dim url As String
Dim results()
Dim i As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your worksheet")
url = "https://www.oslobors.no/ob/servlets/components?type=nibor&source=feed.index.nibor.INDICES_FIXING&view=DELAYED&columns=ITEM%2C+CLOSENZ%2C+TRADE_TIME%2C+CLOSE_DATE%2C+CHANGENZ%2C+CHANGENZ_PCT&filter=ITEM_SECTOR%3D%3DsNIBOR3M.NIBOR&channel=e6da3e88c3464b7ad9620824b8d39c95"
With req
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    Set respJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With
ReDim results(1 To respJSON("rows")(1)("values").Count, 1 To 2)
i = 1
For Each key In respJSON("rows")(1)("values").Keys
    results(i, 1) = key
    results(i, 2) = respJSON("rows")(1)("values")(key) 'write the results in an array
    i = i + 1
Next key
sht.Cells(1, "A").Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results 'Print the results array in one go. The results will be printed to an area/range starting with cell A1 and expanding as much as it is needed

End Sub
```

For demonstration purposes, the data is printed in your immediate window:

[image]

You will need to add the following references to your project (VBE>Tools>References):

```
Microsoft WinHTTP Services version 5.1
Microsoft HTML Objects Library
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
```

You will also need to add this [JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to your project. Follow the installation instructions in the link and you should be set to go.

To get the data from the "Historical Prices" table you just have to change the url to this:

```
url = "https://www.oslobors.no/ob/servlets/components?type=table&source=feed.index.nibor.INDICES_FIXING&view=DELAYED&columns=CHANGE_1WEEK_PCT%2C+HIGH_1WEEK%2C+LOW_1WEEK%2C+CHANGE_1MONTH_PCT%2C+HIGH_1MONTH%2C+LOW_1MONTH%2C+CHANGE_YEAR_PCT%2C+HIGH_YEAR%2C+LOW_YEAR%2C+CHANGE_1YEAR_PCT%2C+HIGH_1YEAR%2C+LOW_1YEAR&filter=ITEM_SECTOR%3D%3DsNIBOR3M.NIBOR&channel=283044a7d182ca196a16337ba79f089c"
```

**EDIT**

Modified the code to print the results in a worksheet named "Name of your worksheet".

Comment: Creative solution. +1 for that. But I believe just using a proper API will be more stable and reliable. If they change the name of the tables then all this work has to be redone.

Comment: @Andreas I think that's the closest thing to an API this website offers. If something changes, I think it will probably be reflected in the parameters included in the URL, which is fairly easy to update. If however there is an official API, then indeed that would be the way to go.

Comment: Nice and comprehesive +1

Comment: The same values can be found "all over internet" so there is no reason to grab them from the page where it's the most problematic, in my opinion. As an example a quick google gives me this page: https://www.nordnet.se/mux/web/marknaden/varlden/rantor.html where NIBOR 3 month is listed. Looking at the source it seems to be a simple table.

Comment: @Andreas Oh ok! I am not familiar with this dataset. I thought it was only provided by this particular website. Nice to know.

Comment: Neither was I, but I used the magic of google. :-) Generally stock numbers can be found everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the JSON solution @Stravos Jon I tested it out and it was sophisticated and worked very well. However, the excel model I'm making is a template for other to use, so unless everyone in my team takes the time to enable JSON parser, it only works for me. So, I went with Andreas' URL in my previous VBA code - NIBOR is not quoted everywhere (the Norwegian Nordnet "sibling" presents the quote in a more complex web language again - at least to me - https://www.nordnet.no/market) so thanks to Andreas for finding a quote that is easy to web scrape:)

Comment: @HaakonSilberg no need for everyone to enable it. You just import it to the project (your template) and then share the macro enabled workbook with your colleagues. Scraping tables is much less efficient.

Comment: @StavrosJon ok, so others can run the VBA module and update the values without having a JSON parser? Btw, how can I return the same values as displayed in the immediate window, to cells in excel (which is were I wanted it in the first place)? Your answers are very much appreciated:)

Comment: @HaakonSilberg Exactly. Importing the Json Converter module only takes effect on the specific project/workbook you're working with and not with your windows or excel installation. So, you only need to do it once and then you can share this workbook with your colleagues. The only thing they will have to do is run the macro. I updated the code to write the results in excel. If this helped you, please consider showing your appreciation by upvoting and/or accepting the answer. This helps good quality content to remain relevant.